# Liip Imagine and Vich Uploader Bundle (Symfony)

Tags: symfony, vichuploaderbundle, liipimaginebundle

I encounter a problem when using Liip Imagine Bundle (to generate thumbnails) and Vich Uploader Bundle (to upload images) simultaneously:
Everything was working perfectly until I decided to use the possibility provided by the Vich Uploader Bundle with directory namers (Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\SubdirDirectoryNamer) to reduce the number of images stored in the directories.
As a result, the images are then stored in a subfolder (here first 2 letters of the file name).
Vich finds them, but Liip is unaware of this subdirectory.

Any idea to tell Liip how to find the image in a subfolder?

Thanks

I understand that I have to tell Liip Imagine Bundle how to find the subdir added by Vich but cannot find the way to do it.